# Datatype of pthread_t in pthreads?

Tags: c, pthreads, 64-bit

I have a code in 32 bit in which int is used in place of pthread_t ?
so while porting do i need to change to long in LP64 (64 bit).
What is the datatype of pthread_t ?

Comment: The `pthread_t` type is an opaque type, you're not supposed to know what it really is.

Comment: I once came across a PThread implementation where `pthread_t` was defined as a pointer.

Answer (score 9):

`pthread_t` is an implementation defined type; no assumption should be made on its underlying type.

[POSIX.1-2008](http://pubs.opengroup.org/stage7tc1/basedefs/sys_types.h.html) adds that:

> IEEE Std 1003.1-2001/Cor 2-2004, item XBD/TC2/D6/26 is applied, adding pthread_t to the list of types that are not required to be arithmetic types, thus allowing pthread_t to be defined as a structure.

Answer (score 4):

Use `pthread_t` like you are supposed to. Done.

Answer (score -1):

"What is the datatype of pthread_t ?"

The definition in x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/pthreadtypes.h:27 is

```
typedef unsigned long int pthread_t;
```

Other implementations may differ.

As others have said, it is classified as an opaque value. You should treat it as such.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).